# How to unbind click for children of parent element?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 clickable elements and each is dependent on the previous element being pressed. Is there a way that I can remove the ability to click on the children elements until the parent is clicked?

```
A -> B -> C
```

'A' must be clicked before 'B' and 'C'. When A is clicked, 'B' should become clickable but 'C' should still not be able to be clicked. When 'B' is clicked then 'C' can be clicked.

I'm not even sure if this can be done with JQuery, but if it can, it would be nice and would save me some backend coding.

Is this possible with Jquery?

```
<img src="1.png" />
<img src="2.png" />
<img src="3.png" />
```

Comment: It sure is possible, but why not post some HTML instead of letters and arrows, that way it's easier to see what you really want.

Comment: They are just simple image tags. I've posted them up top.

Comment: Well, that changes everything, now you have three sibling elements, not children, as image elements can't have descendant elements, and you're description isn't very relevant at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML Markup**

```
<div class="A">
   <div class="B">
       <div class="C">
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".A").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("aClicked");
  // Rest of the code on click of A
});

// Will not work untill A is clicked and has a class .aClicked
$(document).on("click", ".A.aClicked .B", function(){
   $(this).addClass("bClicked");
  // Rest of the code on click of B
});


// Will not work untill B is clicked and has a class .bClicked    
$(document).on("click", ".A.aClicked .B.bClicked .C", function(){
  // Rest of the code on click of C
});
```

Comment: Thank you void. How would I unbind the click from the children though? This is where I am stuck. I don't want to necessarily hide the child elements, but rather to make them unclickable until the parent is clicked. Am I missing something?

Comment: That is what this code is doing. C won't be clickable until B is clicked and B won't be clickable until A is clicked.

Comment: Would my `bClicked` class be `display:hidden`?

Comment: No, It is just a class name used to enable the click on child if the parent has this class.

Comment: OK, thanks Void. I'll credit you for the answer when the time expires. I'm still not understanding how the click events are disabled, but I will play with it and see what it's doing.

Comment: Let me explain you, the third `click` on `C` will not trigger until the selector is `.A.aClicked .B.bClicked .C` now A will have class `aClicked` only when it is been clicked and B will have class `bClicked` only when it is clicked. So at the end when until A and B are clicked you can not click C.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about adding a flag class to element that could be clicked? After click on A you add this class to B (or a .data('clickable', 'true') eg if you don't like classes) and so on.

Comment: I think that would be just fine. How would I unbind the element from being clicked though?

Comment: stopPropagation usually may help with nested html. `$('.item').on('click', function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); /*code*/ })` . If that is what you are asking about